# React-Native to close native FaceID permission popup

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, face-id

I'm working on an application where I'm using FaceID for iOS app login and it asks for the app permission for the first time, the problem that I'm facing is that I have an app timeout feature enabled where the app logs out automatically if it kept ideal for one minute, so due to which if I don't take any action on the FaceID permission popup and kept it ideal, it will logout from the app, while the popup stays as it is.

I want to close the popup without any action along with logout.

I am not sure to handle it programmatically

I don't want to use any external library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing lot of research, I found that it's not possible due to security reasons, the mobile OS doesn't allow us to do so